# Prove that there is no integer k such that $f(k)=8$

Tags: polynomials

Given, $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^na_{i}x^{n-i}$ and $a_0=1$ have integral coefficients.If there exist four distinct integers **a,b,c and d** such that $f(a)=f(b)=f(c)=f(d)=5$,show that there is no integer $k$ such that $f(k)=8$

Source: An Excursion In Mathematics: For [RMO and INMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_National_Mathematical_Olympiad)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I have tried plugging in the values and subtracting one from the other. But could not understand  anything. I think induction needs to be applied. But don't know how

Comment: If it were just three distinct integers $f(x)=x^3-3x^2-x+8$ then $f(-1)=f(1)=f(3)=5$ and $f(0)=8$

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182593/test-for-an-integer-solution) is different from what you're asking, but it does at least give some insight as to how you might prove that integer-coefficient polynomials satisfying integer-value restrictions can be shown to have no integer-valued solutions at integer points. So actually the problems are remarkably similar and the tools developed there may be of some use to you.

Comment: What's the source of this problem, please?

Comment: Clearly all of $a,b,c,d$ need to have the same parity. Otherwise, see [this problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/83592/11619), $f(m)$ will be odd for all $m$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hint: Write $g(x)=f(x)-5$ by hypotesis $g(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)h(x)$. Thus if there exists such $k$ we have $3=(k-a)(k-b)(k-c)(k-d)h(k)$, and you can conclude.